# Run a node package via node

Tags: node.js, windows

I am trying to run a node package.

Technically, I can simply do `./node_modules/.bin/<package name>` from my project's root folder, or even `npx <package name>` from any folder.

But I need to run node with a specific configuration of `max-old-space-size` set to `4096`.

I am therefore trying to invoke it as follows:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/<package name>
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
<root folder>\node_modules\.bin\<package name>:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I am pretty sure that this problem is due to the fact that I am running on Windows.

I did some research and came across [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/Cretezy/Noderize/issues/5), which makes me even more confident that the problem is OS-related.

But I haven't been quite able to find a workable solution within this thread.

The only clue that I have found is by *sc0ttwad3* from 12 days ago, suggesting to change this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/<package name>
```

To this:

```
./node_modules/<package name>/bin/<package name>.js
```

But there is no such `js` file in this path (in fact, there is not even a `bin` folder in this path).

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Look at the `package.json` file in `./node_modules/package name` and see what file the `"bin"` property points at as it might not be in a `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Thank you, I will do that now, but in any case, I searched for `<package name>.js` throughout the entire `node_modules` folder and there was no such file.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: This is what I do see where you pointed at: `"./build/cli.bundled.js"`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Woohoo, that's working!!! (I honestly hope it's an OS-agnostic solution, though I have no way to test it).

Comment: I'm really glad that work for you. I don't see it being OS dependent. What your solution does is call the Javascript file that Javascript file that the Javascript file that the `./node_modules/.bin/package name` shell script points to directly with node

Comment: The main issue with the solution is that it depends on the layout of the package in question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Yes, I'm aware of that issue, which makes it a package-dependent solution. But since I'm applying it on a specific package, assuming its layout is not likely to change, I have no problem with that (in opposed to an OS-dependent solution). Thanks again!!!

Comment: Absolutely, glad I could help.